# Connect to SQL Server running on a distant VM from my desktop

Tags: sql-server, virtual-machine, ssms, connexion, remote-connection

I have created an SQL Server on a VM. When I try to connect to my SQL Server on the VM, everything is fine but when I try to connect to it from my desktop via SSMS I have this problem :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections

I have : 
Enabled SQL Server authentication mode 
Created a SQL login 
Enabled TCP/IP protocol 
Enabled firewall rule for the SQL Server port

but still getting the same error.

Comment: Is the VM "somewhere" else?
On what firewall did you enable the SQL port (1433)?

Comment: Well something's missing but it's hard to say what without more information. On which port is the SQL Server instance listening on the VM? Are you trying to connect to a Named Instance (e.g.: `ServerNameOrIpAddress\SomeInstanceNameHere`), or directly to the listening port (e.g.: `ServerNameOrIpAddress,PortNumberHere`)?

Comment: @LouisvanTonder , yes the machine is somewhere else, and I enabled the port by adding an inbound rule  in windows defenser firewal and I set the TCP/IP sql server port to 1433 and I enabled it then I checked the distant connexion in my sql server and it is enabled too

Comment: On the machine with SSMS, are you able to open a PowerShell window and run `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName ServerNameOrIpAddressHere -Port 1433` (or whatever the listening port number is) and get successful ping and connection results?

Comment: Depending on where your VM is hosted, you need to make sure that it is accessible from the "outside". Setting rules on the windows firewall wont help if there is a firewall in place with the hosting company, before it reaches your box.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning  ComputerName     : IpAddressHere
RemoteAddress    : IpAddressHere
RemotePort       : 1433
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet0
SourceAddress    : IpAddressHere
TcpTestSucceeded : True

Comment: @LouisvanTonder I suspected the same reason , I will check with the administrator of the VM